# Different maven versions cause extra libraries to be included in WAR file

Tags: maven-2, war, maven-3

I'm trying to build a war file to be deployed to a tomcat server using Maven, but have noticed some strange behaviour when building my war file:

When running the command from project folder: `mvn clean compile package -DskipTests`

- Maven version 3.0 produces a war file
  12.079MB (49 jar files in WEB-INF/lib folder)
- Maven version 3.0 beta1
  produces a war file 8.7MB (31 jar
  files in WEB-INF/lib folder)
- Maven version 2.11 produces a war file 2.3MB (3 jar files in WEB-INF/lib folder)

What can be causing the extra jar files to be included in the project? Presumably they are not needed as building the project using version 2.11 has worked fine in the past.

Comment: I think it will be easier to help you if you show the pom of the project in your question.

Comment: Do you use some setup for skinny wars ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had something similar happen to me.  Here's what happened.

In Maven 2.x the plugin versions are set by Maven itself.  In Maven 3.x it will use the "latest" and give you a warning.  In my case, using a later version of the compiler plugin caused some differences and a later version of the dependency plugin cause other differences.

Once I explicitly set all the versions of all plugins in my pom.xml (a best practice anyway), the inconsistencies went away.